# SharePoint Document library events

Tags: 2010

I am not a SharePoint developer or developer for that matter. However, I have this question around file uploads to document libraries.

Is there a way I can hook in to a document upload event, perform some activity on the document being uploaded, and then upload the document to DB?

I am using SharePoint 2010. I have a fair amount of knowledge in PowerShell and a bit of C#. I tried looking at the event handlers through PowerShell but that is too much of work and I have not found (yet) a way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a developer as well but I think it should be possible to do that using an ListEventReceiver. 
Something like this: 
 http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/03/11/list-event-receivers.aspx